# Tell me any better way to sync Realm database with Firebase

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, realm, rx-java

I'm working on a project where i'm using Realm database and Firebase with RxJava 2. In my project, I have User activity that will list all registered users which are stored in Firebase database.Also I have to stored all registered users into Realm Database(Incase if Internet unavailable). So everytime when user starts the activity,my observable will run and fetch all registered users one by one and stored them in Realm database and when observable will complete, data will populate on recyclerview from Realm Database. Here is my code

```
class AllUsers : AppCompatActivity(){
private var recyclers : RecyclerView ?= null
private var toolbars : Toolbar ?= null
private var toolbar_text : TextView ?= null
private var userAdapter : UserAdapter ?= null
private var userModelList : ArrayList<RequestPojo> ?= null
private var databaseReference : DatabaseReference ?= null
private var compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable ?= null
private var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth ?= null
private var currentUserUid : String ?= null
private var realm : Realm?= null
private var requestController : RequestsController ?= null
private var suggestedFriendsController : SuggestedFriendsController ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.allusers)
    initialize()
}
private fun initialize(){
    compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    userModelList = ArrayList()
    toolbars = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    recyclers = findViewById(R.id.recycler)
    toolbar_text = toolbars?.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_text1)
    toolbar_text?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    toolbar_text?.text = "Users"
    setSupportActionBar(toolbars)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    getSupportActionBar()?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
    userAdapter = UserAdapter(this,userModelList)
    recyclers?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    var recyclerlayoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclers?.setLayoutManager(recyclerlayoutmanager)
    val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(recyclers?.getContext(),
            recyclerlayoutmanager.orientation)
    recyclers?.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
    recyclers?.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    recyclers?.setAdapter(userAdapter)
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    currentUserUid = firebaseAuth?.currentUser?.uid
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    databaseReference?.keepSynced(true)
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    requestController = RequestsController()
    suggestedFriendsController = SuggestedFriendsController()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    loadUsersFromFirebase()
    populateDataFromRealm()
}

fun populateDataFromRealm(){
    suggestedFriendsController?.getAllAsync()
            ?.subscribe({
                t: RealmSuggestedFriends? ->  var requestPojo = RequestPojo()
                requestPojo?.email = t?.friendEmail
                requestPojo?.image = t?.friendImage
                requestPojo?.name = t?.friendName
                requestPojo?.status = t?.friendStatus
                requestPojo?.thumb_image = t?.friendThumbImage
                requestPojo?.uid = t?.friendUid
                userAdapter?.addData(requestPojo)
            },{
                t: Throwable? ->  t?.printStackTrace()
            },{

            },{
                t: Disposable? ->compositeDisposable?.add(t!!)
            })
}

fun loadUsersFromFirebase(){
    Observable.create<DataSnapshot>{ emitter ->
        databaseReference
                ?.child("Users")
                ?.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {}
                    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}
                    override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}
                    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
                        if(!emitter.isDisposed){
                            if (!p0?.key?.equals(currentUserUid)!!){
                                emitter.onNext(p0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {}
                })
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : Observer<DataSnapshot>{
                override fun onComplete() {}

                override fun onNext(t: DataSnapshot) {
                        val userModel = t.getValue(RequestPojo::class.java)
                        userModel?.uid = t.key

                    suggestedFriendsController?.addSuggestedFriends(userModel)
                }
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                compositeDisposable?.add(d)
                }
                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            })
}

private fun showMessage(message : String?) {
    Toast.makeText(this@AllUsers,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()
    userModelList?.clear()
    userAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    finish()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    compositeDisposable?.clear()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    realm?.close()
}
```

}

Here is my Realm Controller which will cover all Realm methods to store, retrieve and update data.

```
class SuggestedFriendsController {

fun addSuggestedFriends(requestPojo: RequestPojo?) {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { r->
            r?.executeTransaction { realm ->
                val realmFriends = RealmSuggestedFriends()
                realmFriends.friendEmail = requestPojo?.email
                realmFriends.friendImage = requestPojo?.image
                realmFriends.friendName = requestPojo?.name
                realmFriends.friendStatus = requestPojo?.status
                realmFriends.friendThumbImage = requestPojo?.thumb_image
                realmFriends.friendUid = requestPojo?.uid
                realmFriends.requestSent = "No"
                realm.insertOrUpdate(realmFriends)
            }
    }
}

fun getSuggestedFriendSync(realm : Realm?,uid : String?): RealmSuggestedFriends? =
    realm?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)?.equalTo("friendUid",uid)?.findFirst()

fun getRequestStateAsync(uid: String?) =
    Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
        val real = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        try{
            val res = real?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
                        ?.equalTo("friendUid", uid)
                        ?.findFirst()
            emitter.onNext(res?.requestSent!!)
            emitter.onComplete()
        }catch(e : Exception){
           emitter.onError(Throwable("read failed"))
        }
        finally {
            real?.close()
        }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

fun getAllAsync() = Observable.create<List<RealmSuggestedFriends>> { emitter ->
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        val results = realm?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
                ?.findAll()
        emitter.onNext(realm?.copyFromRealm(results)!!)
    }
}.flatMapIterable { list -> list }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

fun updateSuggestedFriendAsync(uid: String?, request_type: String?) =
        Single.create<String>{emitter ->
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
                try {
                    realm?.beginTransaction()
                    var suggested = realm.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
                            .equalTo("friendUid", uid)
                            .findFirst()!!
                    suggested.requestSent = request_type
                   var d = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(suggested)

                    realm?.commitTransaction()
                    emitter.onSuccess(d?.requestSent!!)
                }catch (e : Exception){
                    emitter.onError(Throwable(e.message))
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

}

Now whenever i starts my activity, my observable will run and fetch each user from Firebase and stored them in Realm database.

1. So Is there any better way that could lead me to run observable only when new user is registered and in case if no new user is registered then my observable should not run.

2 Also Is there any better way to synchronize my Realm Database with Firebase server.

Please suggest me..Thanks in advance.